# Surface of 5-sided pyramid

Tags: geometry

I have to find the surface of a five-sided pyramid. The edges are all 8 cm long. I think I know how to solve this, but I keep getting different solutions.

**My attempt**

The surface is the area of five equilateral triangles plus the area of the pentagon.
$$P=5*\frac{a\sqrt3}{4}+\frac{5a^2\cot\frac{180^\circ}{5}}{4}$$
$$P=5*\frac{8\sqrt3}{4}+\frac{5*8^2\cot\frac{180^\circ}{5}}{4}$$
$$P=17.3+110.1=127.4$$
This seems all right to me, but I’m not sure, also because the solution in my workbook is 460 cm. Please tell me if I used the right formula and if my answer is correct or not.

Comment: You forgot $a^2$ in the first term.

Comment: @Intelligenti pauca,yes,you are right.That's probably why I got a bigger number last time I tried solving this.Thanks for reminding me.